# Get number of weeks of specific year and month

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

In Oracle SQL, I want to get the number of weeks of specific month and year. For example: Input will be  2019 as year 8 as month it includes 5 weeks in it.

```
PROCEDURE SP_WEEKS(P_REFCURSOR OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,P_YEAR IN NUMBER:=-1,P_MONTH IN NUMBER:=-1)  IS
  BEGIN
       OPEN P_REFCURSOR FOR

       --here will return table
  END SP_WEEKS
```

And result will be

```
ID  NAME
--  ----
1     1
2     2
3     3
4     4
5     5
```

`ID` and `NAME` is week number. How can I write this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: is the input always one year and one month?

Comment: Also the expected results for  2019  and month 8 (August) the results should be 31 to 35 for the id and name columns.. right? As i don't assume you want 1 to 5 there.

Comment: @RaymondNijland yes always month and year. Output will not be week of year otuput will be week of month.

Comment: How are you defining a week? e.g September 2019 could be considered to have 5 or 6 weeks, depending on whether you think a week starts on a Sunday or a Monday. Or if you start counting on the 1st of the month then all months have 5 weeks except February in non-leap years (and you can get that with the  W date format element).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand well your need, you may try:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_WEEKS(P_REFCURSOR OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,P_YEAR IN NUMBER:=-1,P_MONTH IN NUMBER:=-1)  IS
BEGIN
     OPEN P_REFCURSOR FOR
     select level as ID, level as NAME
      from dual
      connect by add_months( date '0001-01-01', 12*P_YEAR + P_MONTH -1) + (level -1)*7
              <= last_day(add_months( date '0001-01-01', 12*P_YEAR + P_MONTH -1));
END SP_WEEKS;
```

For example:

```
SQL> var result refcursor
SQL> begin
  2    SP_WEEKS(:result, 2019, 8);
  3  end;
  4  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print :result

        ID       NAME
---------- ----------
         1          1
         2          2
         3          3
         4          4
         5          5
```

This uses a commonly used technique to generate rows by starting with the first day of the given month and adding 7 days for each iteration (`LEVEL`); the `CONNECT BY` condition stops the iteration when the resulting date is not in the month.